# Tramp into gcloud compute engine instance using custom `gssh` and `tunnel-through-iap`

Tags: spacemacs, tramp, ssh

I have a couple of GCP projects which has IAP enabled on them and have compute engine instances which only have private IPs. So the only way to `ssh` into them is to use `gcloud compute ssh` with `tunnel-through-iap` flag.

I love emacs Tramp and I though it would be great if I could tramp into these instances.
I've followed [this](https://modernduck.com/2018/02/gcloud-compute-ssh-improvements-emacs-tramp-mode/) guide to define a `gssh` binary which looks like this.

```
cat ~/.local/bin/gssh
#!/bin/bash

HOST="$1"

if [[ $HOST = *"@"* ]] ; then
    USER=$(echo $HOST | cut -d'@' -f1)
    HOST=$(echo $HOST | cut -d'@' -f2)
fi

gcloud config list | grep 'Your active'
ZONE=$(gcloud compute instances list |grep -E "^$HOST[[:space:]]" | awk '{print $2}')
echo zone: $ZONE
gcloud compute ssh --zone=$ZONE "$@" --tunnel-through-iap
```

Then I've added this to `.zshrc` and sourced this file.
Verified this works by actually `gssh`ing into some instances.

I update the `.spacemacs` function `dotspacemacs/user-config` to include the below config.

```
  ;; TRAMP gcloud ssh
  (add-to-list 'tramp-methods
               '("gssh"
                 (tramp-login-program        "gssh")
                 (tramp-login-args           (("%h")))
                 (tramp-async-args           (("-q")))
                 (tramp-remote-shell         "/bin/sh")
                 (tramp-remote-shell-args    ("-c"))
                 (tramp-gw-args              (("-o" "GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null")
                                              ("-o" "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null")
                                              ("-o" "StrictHostKeyChecking=no")))
                 (tramp-default-port         22)))
```

When I try to tramp into some of these instances using `/gssh:<user>@<instane_name>:` syntax, emacs starts listing local directories on my laptop.
I tried looking at the `debug tramp/gssh` and [this](https://justpaste.it/8p3ic) is what I found.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The debug traces are not complete. For analysis, you must enable traces prior opening the connection, and provide the whole buffer. Furthermore, `tramp-gw-args` are not used anymore. Where do you get them from?

Comment: What is GCP? What is IAP?

Comment: For your trace output, consider increasing the value of user option `tramp-verbose`.

Comment: You may be able to use the configuration that is printed with the `--dry-run` flag to setup ssh without using the gcloud cli (see https://medium.com/@albert.brand/remote-to-a-vm-over-an-iap-tunnel-with-vscode-f9fb54676153 )